# How to send mp3 through whatsapp?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, media-files

I [see](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/bb/20991682) that you can send a media file on BlackBerry. Can I do the same thing on Android?

Answer (score 15):

Yes you can send a mp3 file through WhatsApp in Android.

- Go to a private chat/group chat where you want to send the mp3 file.
- Find the clip icon in the top right corner of the chat.

  [image: WhatsApp Attach]
- Tap it and a menu looking like this will pop up.

  [image: WhatsApp Attach menu]
- Choose "Audio" and then choose "Choose Music Track" (Play Music app) or from a third party music app.
- Choose the track you wish to send and then confirm.
- The mp3 file will be received (by default) in `Internal Storage > WhatsApp > Media > WhatsApp Audio`

---

Alternative Solution #1,

- Locate the mp3 file you wish to send in a file explorer.
- Depending on the file explorer, either long-clicking or choosing options will give you a menu with all operations such as cut, copy, rename, details, share (or send).
- Choose share (or send) and then choose WhatsApp from the pop-up menu.
- Now choose the contact you wish to send to and confirm.

---

Alternative solution #2,

- Use a third-party application to send the file over a chat.
- Good examples are [WaSend](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.twinscreations.wasend&hl=en) and [WhatsApp File Sender](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp.share.all.types.files.sender).

Comment: I only get the 'sound record' and 'record with whatsapp' options

Comment: Try the alternative solutions.

Comment: good enough, although the 2nd solution doesn't really answer the question asked

Comment: +1 good answer! @svarog The 2nd solution may not address the exact parameters you defined, but remember others will be reading this and in some cases an alternative app / extension may be exactly what that person wants! The more options the better (in my opinion anyway).

Comment: It's still useful nevertheless, that's why I upvoted the answer

Answer (score 3):

Go to file manager. Find the mp3 you want to send. Long press on it for 1 second. Then select "Share" option. Then select Whatsapp in the sharelist. That's it. You're done.